# Using the % operator on path keys throws and error

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

[In the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#_modulus) for the firabase realtime database it says for the `%` sign:

> Used to find the remainder of dividing one variable by another in a rules expression. 
> This write rule grants write access to users with even-numbered user IDs:
>
> ```json
> "$user_id": {
>  ".write": "$user_id % 2 === 0"
> }
> ```

However when i try to use it, it throws an error saying that "left operand is not number".

[image]

They touch on this briefly [in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#_add):

> Note: PATH KEYS ARE ALWAYS STRINGS. Because keys are always strings, attempting to compare a $ variable to a number will always fail. This can be corrected by converting the number to a string using the + operator.

However I think I must have misunderstood it, because I keep getting the same error.

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

I tried myself and asked around, and it looks like there is no way to convert the key to a number here, which is what is required for the `%` to be possible. The only way to implement this scenario would be to (also) include the `user_id` as the value of a property in the JSON, and not just as a key.

Sorry about the documentation misfire. I've filed a bug for this, and will get it updated in the documentation shortly.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunate answer, but thanks for asking around.
Is the bug tracker public? I'd like to keep an eye on the discussion.

Comment: It isn't. But the fix is already live on https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database#_modulus